# Nested resource route triggers parent resource route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ember.js

I have such **router** in my app:

```
TravelApi.Router.map ->
  @resource 'stars', ->
    @resource 'star', { path: '/:star_id' }
```

When I go to `http://localhost/#/stars`
I see in web console that there is one request

> GET http://localhost:3000/stars

And when I go to `http://localhost/#/stars/1`
I see in web console that there are two requests

> GET http://localhost:3000/stars
>
> GET http://localhost:3000/stars/1

**Question: why there are two requests in the second case?**

---

Stars **route**:

```
TravelApi.StarRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: (params) ->
    TravelApi.Star.find(params.star_id)
)

TravelApi.StarsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    TravelApi.Star.find()
)
```

And my **templates**:
application.js.hbs.hamlbars

```
= hb "linkTo 'stars'" do
  stars
%div= hb 'outlet'
```

stars.js.hbs.hamlbars

```
%ul
  =hb "each star in controller" do
    %li<
      =hb 'star.name'
```

star.js.hbs.hamlbars

```
Star:
= hb 'name'
```

**store**.js.coffee

```
TravelApi.store = DS.Store.create(
  revision: 11
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
)
```

Comment: it really shouldn't make a 2nd request if you already have that record in `Store`. Can you add the definition of your `Store`? do you have a custom primary key for it? Also, in the `StarRoute`, try changing it to `App.store.find('App.Star', params.star_id)`. Not sure if it would make any difference tho, but try it out

Comment: Now you can see my store definition. Also I change primary key in json from **_id** to **id** (because of mongoid). I also add outlet into stars.js.hdb.hamlbars. Now I have two requests only at first resource load but if I load stars before than I have only one request each time I load the special star (by id) ***GET http://localhost:3000/stars ***

Answer (score 1):

The way nested resources work, if the first request returns a promise (which ember data is supposed to do), the nested resource/route model function will not be called until after the ajax request will complete.

Following this logic, there should only be 1 ajax call.

`TravelApi.Star.find()` should create an ajax request to fetch all records
`TravelApi.Star.find(1)` should not require an ajax request because the record should be there.

In your case however, the `star` resource is not waiting for the `stars` resource to finish the ajax.  The reason is `TravelApi.Star.find()` returns results immediately (which are all available records in the store which of course is empty), instead of a promise  (I think).

To solve this, you can return a findQuery promise by writing the following in your model:
`TravelApi.Star.find({})`

This will cause the `star` resource to wait for the `stars` resource to finish its ajax request.

The route should look like this:

```
TravelApi.StarsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    TravelApi.Star.find({})

TravelApi.StarRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    TravelApi.Star.find(params.star_id)
```

Comment: If I remove the **params.star_id** from my route then I haven't any request by **id**. So this doesn't work.

Comment: This is the Stars route not the Star route. Keep the params.star_id in the star route.

Comment: Ok I tried it but it hasn't any effect. Just as I describe in comment above.

Comment: You used my routes and still saw 2 ajax requests?

Comment: I did the following:
I change primary key in json from _id to id (because of mongoid). I also add outlet into stars.js.hdb.hamlbars. 
I have the following behaviour:
Two requests only at first resource load but if I load stars before than I have only one request each time I load the special star (by id) **GET localhost:3000/stars **
I tried your suggestion and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It looks to me like we're both trying to solve different problems.  My suggestion lets you avoid localhost:3000/stars/1 request. If that's what you're trying to avoid, my solution should work. But it seems to me you are trying to avoid localhost:3000/stars request, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. At first I wanted to avoid localhost:3000/stars/1 request. Now there are not this request according to my previous comment so I achieved that not by your suggestion but by actions described in the my last comment. Now my problem is that I have localhost:3000/stars request each time I load the specify star (by id).

Comment: When you say 
> I have localhost:3000/stars request each time I load the specified star

Do you mean on page refresh (directly through the URL localhost:3000/star/1), or by clicking on a link inside the application?

Comment: I mean the url change in the address bar and enter pressing. Do you think that this is the root of current problem?

Comment: Yes, check my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't want to fetch all the stars when you load /star/:id

The reason why all the stars are fetched if you access /star/1 directly is because the `star` route is nested inside `stars`

The reason why you would nest your routes, is because your UI is nested.  This means that when you are looking at one star, somewhere in your UI (in the side bar maybe), you are showing the list of stars.  In that case, you need the request `localhost:3000/stars` because you need to display all the stars even if you are looking at one star.  This means that the ajax requested is necessary and therefore not a problem.

If however, you are not displaying the list of all the the stars when looking at one star, then your routes shouldn't be nested in the first place.  In that case, fix your routes to look like this:

```
TravelApi.Router.map ->
  @resource 'stars'
  @resource 'star', { path: '/:star_id' }
```

Comment: Ok I guessed this. But if I already load all stars, why this(by id) query loads everything again instead of reading from memory?